# NSpredicate "and" operation not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have this following data when i getall the values from a core data entity when i loop and print values i have this

- **type : invitedBy : mobile**
- emp : 1 : 1234123131
- emp : 1 : 2314213211
- cust: 1 : 1214212312
- cust: 1 : 2412142121
- cust: 1 : 5421321421
- emp : 2 : 3214213211

I want to filter all the records which are not of type emp and not invited by 1 all the values are of type string. so my predicate is

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(type != %@) && (invitedBy != %@)","emp", "1")
```

when i get values with this predicate it is returning empty insted of last 4 values.

If i have to write query in mysql i would have written

```
SELECT * FROM invite where type != "emp" AND invitedBy != "1"
```

So is the predicate i have written wrong, and should i differently.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: None of those objects matches the predicate. Perhaps you meant “not of type emp **OR** not invited by 1”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your predicate again:

> ```
> NSPredicate(format: "(type != %@) && (invitedBy != %@)","emp", "1")
> ```

Substituting for `%@`, it is the same as

```
(type != 'emp') && (invitedBy != '1')
```

Your complaint is

> when i get values with this predicate it is returning empty insted of last 4 values.

Here's your last record:

> emp : 2 : 3214213211

Let's substitute into the predicate and simplify:

```
('emp' != 'emp') && ('2' != '1')
FALSE && TRUE
FALSE
```

So the predicate is false for the last record. In fact, it is false for all the records. You can test the other records by hand yourself to verify.

If you want a predicate that is true for the last four records, you probably want this instead:

```
NSPredicate(format: "(type != %@) || (invitedBy != %@)","emp", "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's right for return empty.
[image: screenshot]